# Удаление данных, если прошел 1 год! MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Удаление данных о клиентах и оказанных им услугах, если со дня последнего их обращения в клинику прошел 1 год
(ключевое слово СО ДНЯ ПОСЛЕДНЕГО, то есть если обращений было несколько, то проверяется последнее)

ТАБЛИЦА БОЛЬНЫЕ
ПОЛЯ: id, name, age

ТАБЛИЦА Мед. Осмотр
Поля: id, id_больной, симптомы, лечение, ДАТА осмотра, и тд...

Ума не приложу как эти все условия до кучи собрать. Помоги пожалуста, желательно корректный запрос набросать))

Answer (score 1):

Вам помогут [NOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189455.aspx) [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188336.aspx) + [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189794.aspx)